# compile vim/gvim from source on Windows 8

Tags: vim, vi

My workplace has only a limited set of software to choose from and I cannot download any executable files from the Internet. Any .exe I download would not run.
One of the tools I'm terribly missing is my favorite editor gvim. Who uses TextPad?

I do not even have the Admin rights on my machine.

I have eclipse installed and have java, python and other compilers. I can get C compiler as well. I cannot install visual studio either. That's pretty much all I have.

I have already downloaded vim source from https://github.com/vim/vim

Is there a way to build and install vim from source with given tools?

Comment: Did you read [src/INSTALL](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/INSTALL) instructions? Have you tried just running `make`? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: I know it is not as good as the Vim itself but Eclipse offers a Plug-In for Vim-Like movement and a hand full of other features. If it is not much you need this may be an alternative.

Comment: Are there really no other ways around the restriction? Can you put vim.exe in a ZIP file, just replace the `.exe` file extension, or Base64-encode the vim.exe?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Visual Studio, but these prerequisites:

- [Microsoft .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851)
- [Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442)

From the Start Menu, open a *Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt*: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.cmd" /release`

Then, build with `nmake -f Make_mvc.mak`.

You can pass options (e.g. `GUI=yes`); see `INSTALLpc.txt` from the Vim sources.

Comment: or just use msys2